# Listing and deleting hidden files?

Tags: vbscript, hidden-files

I'm writing a VB Script that will place a series of folders on a USB thumbstick.  When this USB thumbstick is used, these folders get hidden (an intended feature). I'm attempting to make it such that if this script is run it will wipe out the thumbstick and then replace the files, but I'm running into some serious issues getting the folders to actually be deleted.

I'm clearing all files and folders with this segment of code:

```
For Each f In folder.Files
    On Error Resume Next
    name = f.Name
    f.Delete True
    If Err Then
        WScript.Echo "Error deleting: " & name & " - " & Err.Description
    End If
Next

For Each f In folder.SubFolders
    On Error Resume Next
    f.Attributes = 0
    name = f.Name
    f.Delete True
    If Err Then
        WScript.Echo "Error deleting: " & name & " - " & Err.Description
    End If
Next
```

This is not listing the hidden folders, and I cannot seem to locate the hidden files with a `FileSystemObject` manually.  I've tried setting file attributes with no luck.

Am I missing something here?  Is it impossible to access hidden files through VBScripts?

Comment: The "hidden" attribute doesn't affect `FileSystemObject` methods.

Comment: Not sure what to say then.  I can't delete them or replace them with vbs.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I executed your script and got all hidden files deleted. Keep in mind that a folder has to be empty in order to delete it.